# Grey Outline Appearing on Buttons, Unsure of Cause

Tags: html, css

[image]

For some reason, all of my buttons are receiving a grey outline and I'm completely unsure of the source of it. It is not a hover or active thing, it is an always kind of thing. I can also note that it is not the on-click border that a browser adds to buttons, as I've removed that with a :focus value.

This is in Google Chrome. I'm not sure if the issue is present in other browsers.

```css
.button_default {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #1188f0;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2e8cff), color-stop(100%,#1188f0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #2e8cff 0%, #1188f0 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1c95ff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1c95ff inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1c95ff inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
    transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #006ac7;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.button_default:hover {
    background: #1995fa;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2e8cff), color-stop(100%,#2e8cff));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #2e8cff 0%, #2e8cff 100%);
}
.button_default:active {
 cursor: wait;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1491ff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1491ff inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1491ff inset;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;
    transition: background-position 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(3px);
    transform: translateY(3px);
}
.button_default:focus {
  outline:0;
}
```

```html
<form method="link" action="create/create.php">
  <input class="button_default" type="submit" value="CREATE NEW">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default `border` from the buttons: `border: none`.

```css
.button_default {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #1188f0;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2e8cff), color-stop(100%,#1188f0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #2e8cff 0%, #1188f0 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1c95ff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1c95ff inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1c95ff inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
    transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #006ac7;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.button_default:hover {
    background: #1995fa;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2e8cff), color-stop(100%,#2e8cff));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #2e8cff 0%, #2e8cff 100%);
}
.button_default:active {
 cursor: wait;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1491ff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1491ff inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #006391, 0px -1px 0px 0px #1491ff inset;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;
    transition: background-position 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(3px);
    transform: translateY(3px);
}
.button_default:focus {
  outline:0;
}

input[type="submit"].button_default { border: none;}
```

```html
<form method="link" action="create/create.php">
  <input class="button_default" type="submit" value="CREATE NEW">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your response though.

Answer (score 0):

The button has a default border, add border: 0 to your CSS

```
.button_default {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #1188f0;
    ...
    ...
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove the border:

```
.button_default {
  border:none;
}
```

This question was previously posed here: [Button border & background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205114/button-border-background)